# Apache2 LDAP subgroup check

Tags: apache, ldap, apache2

Hi i'm trying to check with ldap if a user exists in a group or any of the subgroups.
currently i'm trying with the following:

```
  <Location /sandbox.git>
    Deny from All
    DAV off
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Git"

    ###############################################################################
    AuthLDAPMaxSubGroupDepth 100 ### THIS IS HOW I TRY TO DEEP SUB-GROUP SEARCH ###
    ###############################################################################

    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://MY-SERVER:389/OU=Domain Users,DC=corp,DC=Company,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
    AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=authUSER,OU=Service Accounts,DC=corp,DC=Company,DC=com"

    Satisfy any

    AuthLDAPBindPassword "********"

    Require ldap-group CN=My_Group,OU=Company,OU=Security Groups,OU=Exchange,DC=corp,DC=Company,DC=com 



  </Location>
```

which is the appropriate for my version of Apache2.4.6

the log seems like this:

```
[access_compat:error]  AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend
[authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(802):  AH01626: authorization result of Require ldap-group CN=My_Group,OU=Company,OU=Security Groups,OU=Exchange,DC=corp,DC=Company,DC=com: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(802):  AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[access_compat:error]  AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend
[authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(802):  AH01626: authorization result of Require ldap-group CN=My_Group,OU=Company,OU=Security Groups,OU=Exchange,DC=corp,DC=Company,DC=com: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(802):  AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[access_compat:error]  AH01797: client denied by server configuration: /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend
[authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(802):  AH01626: authorization result of Require ldap-group CN=My_Group,OU=Company,OU=Security Groups,OU=Exchange,DC=corp,DC=Company,DC=com: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(802):  AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied (no authenticated user yet)
[authnz_ldap:debug] mod_authnz_ldap.c(501):  AH01691: auth_ldap authenticate: using URL ldap://MY-SERVER:389/OU=Domain Users,DC=corp,DC=Company,DC=com?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)
[authnz_ldap:debug] mod_authnz_ldap.c(593):  AH01697: auth_ldap authenticate: accepting testuser
[authnz_ldap:debug] mod_authnz_ldap.c(871):  AH01713: auth_ldap authorize: require group: testing for group membership in "CN=My_Group,OU=Company,OU=Security Groups,OU=Exchange,DC=corp,DC=Company,DC=com"
[authnz_ldap:debug] mod_authnz_ldap.c(879):  AH01714: auth_ldap authorize: require group: testing for member: CN=LastName\\, FirstName (717712),OU=PLACE,OU=Domain Users,DC=corp,DC=Company,DC=com (CN=My_Group,OU=Company,OU=Security Groups,OU=Exchange,DC=corp,DC=Company,DC=com)
[authnz_ldap:debug] mod_authnz_ldap.c(898):  AH01719: auth_ldap authorize: require group "CN=My_Group,OU=Company,OU=Security Groups,OU=Exchange,DC=corp,DC=Company,DC=com": didn't match with attr Comparison false (cached) [member][5 - Compare False]
[authnz_ldap:debug] mod_authnz_ldap.c(879):  AH01714: auth_ldap authorize: require group: testing for uniqueMember: CN=LastName\\, FirstName (717712),OU=PLACE,OU=Domain Users,DC=corp,DC=Company,DC=com (CN=My_Group,OU=Company,OU=Security Groups,OU=Exchange,DC=corp,DC=Company,DC=com)
[authnz_ldap:debug] mod_authnz_ldap.c(898):  AH01719: auth_ldap authorize: require group "CN=My_Group,OU=Company,OU=Security Groups,OU=Exchange,DC=corp,DC=Company,DC=com": didn't match with attr Comparison no such attribute (cached) [uniqueMember][16 - No such attribute]
[authnz_ldap:debug] mod_authnz_ldap.c(915):  AH01716: auth_ldap authorise: require group "CN=My_Group,OU=Company,OU=Security Groups,OU=Exchange,DC=corp,DC=Company,DC=com": failed [Comparison no such attribute (cached)][16 - No such attribute], checking sub-groups
[authnz_ldap:debug] mod_authnz_ldap.c(938):  AH01718: auth_ldap authorise: require group (sub-group) "CN=My_Group,OU=Company,OU=Security Groups,OU=Exchange,DC=corp,DC=Company,DC=com": didn't match with attr DN failed group verification. [member][5 - Compare False]
[authnz_ldap:debug] mod_authnz_ldap.c(915):  AH01716: auth_ldap authorise: require group "CN=My_Group,OU=Company,OU=Security Groups,OU=Exchange,DC=corp,DC=Company,DC=com": failed [DN failed group verification.][5 - Compare False], checking sub-groups
[authnz_ldap:debug] mod_authnz_ldap.c(938):  AH01718: auth_ldap authorise: require group (sub-group) "CN=My_Group,OU=Company,OU=Security Groups,OU=Exchange,DC=corp,DC=Company,DC=com": didn't match with attr DN failed group verification. [uniqueMember][5 - Compare False]
[authnz_ldap:debug] mod_authnz_ldap.c(945):  AH01720: auth_ldap authorize group: authorization denied for user testuser to /sandbox.git/info/refs
[authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(802):  AH01626: authorization result of Require ldap-group CN=My_Group,OU=Company,OU=Security Groups,OU=Exchange,DC=corp,DC=Company,DC=com: denied
[authz_core:debug] mod_authz_core.c(802):  AH01626: authorization result of <RequireAny>: denied
[authz_core:error]  AH01631: user testuser: authorization failure for "/sandbox.git/info/refs":
```

it seems like i am missing a small but important part that makes the deep search in subgroups fail.

Answer (score 2):

Add this lines to your apache config:

```
AuthLDAPGroupAttribute "member"
AuthLDAPSubGroupClass "group"
AuthLDAPSubGroupAttribute "member"
AuthLDAPMaxSubGroupDepth 10
```

may fix the subgroup ldap lookup.

Comment: Could you give some information about your answer, what it does?

Answer (score -1):

You can't express this in the limited syntax that Apache provides, which is a subset of the LDAP filter URL syntax, which itself cannot express your search. All it can express is whether or not a DN exists as an attribute of the specified group. Group nesting cannot be expressed in this syntax.

Comment: i dont understand if this is an answare saying you can't do it. or is there a different way i can do this so it will work?

Comment: Please alternative solution.

Comment: It's true that LDAP query syntax can't express nested group membership, but Apache has explicit support for that kind of search (see the other answer).